# MYSQL relacionamento entre tabelas

Tags: mysql

Não sou muito bom com relacionamento em banco de dados e estou iniciando meus estudos.

Gostaria de saber por que os desenvolvedores encurtam ao chamar as tabelas ou se isso é o obrigatório?

```
SELECT p.*, c.`nome` AS categoria, u.`nome` AS usuario FROM `produtos` AS p
INNER JOIN `categorias` AS c ON p.`categoria_id` = c.`id`
INNER JOIN `usuarios` AS u ON p.`usuario_id` = u.`id`
WHERE (p.`ativo` = 1) ORDER BY p.`nome` ASC
```

isso é muito confuso, eu sei que aí ele está juntando 2 tabelas numa consulta mas não entendo isso:

```
 p.* , p.´nome´,  c.`nome`, u.`nome`
```

Comment: Rafael, não é obrigatório! Eu prefiro colocar nomes na tabela porque não preciso escrever todo o seu texto mesmo. A ideia é abreviar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O item p.* quer dizer que é para exibir todos os campos da tabela produtos. Logo após o FROM, tem escrito produtos as p, isto é um nome curto para que você não precise escrever produtos.*. Como foi criado o apelido p, você simplesmente faz referência utilizando p.*.

O item p.nome, faz referência a tabela produto e coluna nome, diz que é para ordenar o resultado pela coluna nome da tabela produto. É apenas um nome curto, poderia ser escrito produto.nome, mas como citei acima, foi lhe atribuído um apelido "p" e pode ser feita a referência como p.nome.

Esperto ter ajudado.

Comment: Agora entendi.. Muito obrigado!

Comment: Vale lembrar que, se não definisse o apelido (alias) (``produtos as p``, ``categorias c``), o select deveria trazer o nome inteiro das tabelas (``produtos.nome``, ``categorias.nome``), o que deixa um pouco difícil para ler quando está lidando com muitos campos no select.

Answer (score 4):

Geralmente cria-se esse "alias" para as tabelas e colunas para facilitar referencia-las novamente na query.

Por exemplo, ao invés de escrever categoria toda vez, basta escreve c. 
Isso não é obrigatorio, mas quando existem tabelas que você quer relacionar que tem colunas com o mesmo nome, quando você for usar essas colunas você precisa dizer de qual tabela e ai faz sentido usar o alias.

Answer (score 2):

Geralmente usa-se apelidar as tabelas para facilitar a escrita do Script que por sintaxe pede a utilização do "Nome da tabela" e "Nome do campo" (ex: categoria.nome) em casos onde o nome do campo existe em mais de uma tabela.

```
SELECT p.*, c.nome AS categoria, u.nome AS usuario  
FROM produtos p  
INNER JOIN categorias c ON p.categoria_id = c.id  
INNER JOIN usuarios u ON p.usuario_id = u.id  
WHERE (p.ativo = 1)  
ORDER BY p.nome  
ASC
```